# test/unit not running tests because of bundler?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, integration-testing

This is a very strange issue. I have a Sinatra application I want to test. The test I wrote runs fine unless I add the line `Bundler.require(:default)` to my application. When I add it the tests no longer run. The runner reports: `0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips`.

Here is my application:

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require(:default)

class TestApp < Sinatra::Base
  get '/yoyo' do
  end
end
```

Here is my test:

```
require 'rack/test'
gem 'test-unit', '=2.5.5'
require 'test/unit'
require_relative '../../test_app'

class FooTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    TestApp.new
  end

  def test_foo
    assert true
  end
end
```

And here is my Gemfile:

```
gem 'sinatra'
```

If I replace `Bundler.require(:default)` with `require 'sinatra'`, everything's fine. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: how are you running your tests?

Comment: `ruby /path/to/test.rb`